# Android: Prevent focus from jumping when hiding view

Tags: android, android-edittext, focus

I have an Android activity that contains multiple EditText views.

If I programmatically hide the currently focused EditText, then the focus will automatically jump to the next EditText.

Is there anyway to disable this behavior so that the focus is cleared when the EditText is hidden rather than automatically jumping to the next EditText?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to provide `Focus` to a parent view above your `EditText` just like the sample code below

```
  <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/search_edit_text_relative_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true" >

        <EditText...
```

Do try this to avoid providing focus directly to the next `EditText`

Comment: You need to create a ladder of `EditText` --> `RelativeLayout (Child is EditText and so on)`

Comment: Please accept this as `Answer` if it solved your problem